# Convert string to Json in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

My string is like this :

```
"['01',746],['02',0],['03',9994],['04',0],['05',0],['06',0],['07',0],['08',0],['09',0],['10',0],['11',0],['12',0],['13',0],['14',0],['15',0],['16',0],['17',0],['18',0],['19',0],['20',0],['21',0],['22',0],['23',0],['24',0],['25',0],['26',0],['27',0],['28',0],['29',0],['30',0],['31',0]"
```

I have tried $.parseJSON() or JSON.Parse() but does not work . I am gonna use this data for google chart . so i need it in the json format .

how can i do that ?

Comment: because single quotes are not valid in JSON and it is not a valid array format.

Comment: How do you generate this string ? You should fix that generation

Comment: a/ this is not json because single quotes. b/ this is not json because coma separated values outside of an array or an object c/ this is not json because of the outside double quotes.

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert the single quotes to double to be valid and you would need to wrap it in `[]` so it is a valid array format.

```
var str = "['01',746],['02',0],['03',9994],['04',0],['05',0],['06',0],['07',0],['08',0],['09',0],['10',0],['11',0],['12',0],['13',0],['14',0],['15',0],['16',0],['17',0],['18',0],['19',0],['20',0],['21',0],['22',0],['23',0],['24',0],['25',0],['26',0],['27',0],['28',0],['29',0],['30',0],['31',0]";

var myArray = JSON.parse("[" + str.replace(/'/g,'"') + "]");
console.log(myArray[0][0], myArray[0][1]); // "01" 746
```

But a better solution is to fix what is producing that string so it is a valid JSON object to start.